# Anybody knows what is the replacement for this code in IE?..It works in firefox,chrome.( = () => )

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

**CODE :**

```
<script>
    var expectedFunc = () => showAllSteps();

    function showAllSteps() {
        alert('showAllSteps');    
        expectedFunc = () => nextStep();
    }

    function nextStep() {
        alert('nextStep');     
        expectedFunc = () => showAllSteps();
    }

    function toggleFunction() {
        expectedFunc();
    }
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn" name="showAllBtn" onclick="toggleFunction()">Show all</button>
```

In this code expectedFunc = () => showAllSteps();=()=> is not working in IE.Does anyone know what is the replacement for this toggle  in IE ?

Comment: `expectedFunc = showAllSteps;` – You're just defining a function which just calls a function; you may as well just reassign the original function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), so replace it with simple function

```html
<script>
  var expectedFunc = function() {
    showAllSteps()
  };

  function showAllSteps() {
    alert('showAllSteps');
    expectedFunc = function() {
      nextStep()
    };
  }

  function nextStep() {
    alert('nextStep');
    expectedFunc = function() {
      showAllSteps()
    };
  }

  function toggleFunction() {
    expectedFunc();
  }
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn" name="showAllBtn" onclick="toggleFunction()">Show all</button>
```